# Can AirDrop reception be set to be "everyone" without signing in to iCloud on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, airdrop

Computer:

Mac OS Monterey, Version 12.3

Apple M1 Max

I am in Germany and want my Mac to advertise reception to everyone, but that preference isn’t sticking.

My computer is invisible to any devices through AirDrop.
I have tried all methods I could find on the Internet to fix this.
I am setting Allow me to be discovered by: `everyone` in the settings which has no effect.

The suspicious part is, when I turn AirDrop off and on again it defaults to Allow me to be discovered by: `contacts only`.

Any ideas for a solution.

- I do not use iCloud and not willing to.
- I am logged in with my apple ID.

Is this supported or achievable?